# Error Message: “TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current context” while using nested select in hive2.3.3

Tags: select, hive, bigdata

when i use the nested select in hive like this

```
Select 
a.month,
a.day,
sum(a.pv)/count(a.*) 
from 
(Select month,day, remote_addr,count(1) as pv 
from ods_weblog_detail group by remote_addr,month,day) as a;
```

it returns the error message："TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current context".

but when I select a.month,a.day and sum(a.pv)/count(a.*) seperately like this:

```
Select 
sum(a.pv)/count(a.*) 
from 
(Select month,day, remote_addr,count(*) as pv from ods_weblog_detail group by remote_addr,month,day) as a;
```

**OR this:**

```
Select 
a.month,a.day 
from 
(Select month,day, remote_addr,count(*) as pv 
from 
ods_weblog_detail 
group by remote_addr,month,day) as a;
```

**Both statements give me the right answer.**
So why can't I select these three(a.month,a.day and sum(a.pv)/count(a.*)) together in one statement? thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The query is missing a `group by`.

```
Select 
a.month,
a.day,
sum(a.pv)/count(a.*) 
from (select month,day, remote_addr,count(1) as pv 
      from ods_weblog_detail 
      group by remote_addr,month,day
     ) a
group by a.month,a.day
```

The query can also be simplified as below.

```
select month,day,remote_addr
,sum(count(*)) over(partition by month,day,remote_addr)/count(*) over(partition by month,day) as res
from ods_weblog_detail
```